# Makefile error: No rule to make "bin/functions.o", needed by "build"

Tags: makefile

I have four files driver.c, functions.h, functions.c, and input.ppm the function files are in a src directory in the current directory and I am getting this error when trying to make. make: no rule to make target "src/functions.o” needed by "build"

```
    CC=gcc
    CFLAGS= -Wall -g
    LFLAGS=-lm
    TARGET=out
    
    C_SRCS := \
        $(wildcard *.c) \
        $(wildcard src/*.c) \
        $(wildcard src/**/*.c)
    
    HDRS := \
        $(wildcard *.h) \
        $(wildcard src/*.h) \
        $(wildcard src/**/*.h)
    
    OBJS := $(patsubst %.c, bin/%.o, $(wildcard *.c))
    OBJS += $(filter %.o, $(patsubst src/%.c, bin/%.o, $(C_SRCS)))
    
    all: build
        @echo "All Done"
    
    build: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET) $(LFLAGS)
    
    bin/%.o: %.c $(HDRS)
        @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
    bin/$.o: src/$.c $(HDRS)
        @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
    run: build
        ./$(TARGET) input.ppm key decrypt.ppm
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It appears that `src/functions.o` is getting into your `OBJS` list, but I don't see how that's possible. Try printing out the full list (using `$(info $(OBJS))`) and tell us what it is. Then try commenting out the `OBJS += $(filter...` line, run it again and tell us the result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the following rule. Trying fixing it (using '%' instead of '$'). This can break the rule for generating bin/functions.o).

```
bin/$.o: src/$.c $(HDRS)
       @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Should be:

```
bin/%.o: src/%.c $(HDRS)
       @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```